# Twitter authentication for a mobile web page?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-oauth

The typical way to authenticate user with Twitter is to open the Twitter's authentication page in a new window/tab. However, this is a bit clunky with mobile browsers.

Is there any nice pattern how to do this as user friendly as possible? Opening the auth page in an iframe is out of question.

Edit: I am building an HTML5 app that should work both on desktop and mobile browsers.

Comment: I think you've exhausted the options for that type of auth, since the system is going to, for security reasons, want the authorizing domain to be twitter itself.  I would just check out some mobile apps that use that system and duplicate their behavior.  It may well be that you can simply work like a link for mobile-only, going to the auth page and then having the auth page return you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with a mobile app versus a mobile website, yes, you can do this with [xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth). You will need to get approved by the API team though. Not sure how long that takes.

Comment: the Facebook style is much easier here. Did some authorization via it in web-app, and now finishing twitter auth. Otherwise the twitter solution is PHP+JS based, but Facebook is raw JS only.